# YII2 Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object

Tags: yii2

I am new with Yii2, im trying to make sales transaction, but i have problem for dropdownlist in detail section.
for this module, i have 3 tables : 
1. for header, table salesheader 
2. for detail, table salesdetail  
3. for item, table item

this is my code :

on controller :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
            $model = $this->findModel($id); //find appropriate record in salesheader
            //$modeldetail = salesdetail::findModel($id);
            $modeldetail = new salesdetail();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {                   
                    return $this->redirect(['index']);
            } else {

                $item = item::find()->select(["concat('[',code,'] - ', name) as item", "id"])->indexBy('id')->column();
                $detail = salesdetail::find()->select(["*"])->all();    //find appropriate record in salesdetail

                return $this->render('update', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'modeldetail' => $modeldetail,
                        'item' => $item,
                        'detail' => $detail
                ]);
            }
    }
```

on salesheader model

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class salesheader extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'salesheader';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['partnerId', 'date', 'term', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['name', 'invNumber'], 'string'],                      
            [['partnerId', 'term'], 'integer']
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [            
            'partnerId' => 'Customer',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'invNumber' => 'Inv. Number',
                        'term' => 'Term',
                        'name' => 'Name'
        ];
    }
```

on salesdetail model

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class salesdetail extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{    
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'salesdetail';
    }

    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['itemId', 'qty', 'price'], 'required'],
            [['unit'], 'string']
        ];

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {

        return [
            'itemId' => 'Item',
        ];

    }
}
```

on my view

```
<?= $form->field($detail, 'itemId')->dropDownList($item)->label(false) ?>
```

and when open the page in browser, i got this error "Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object"

and if i change this line on controller

```
//$modeldetail = salesdetail::findModel($id);
$modeldetail = new salesdetail();
```

to this one

```
$modeldetail = salesdetail::findModel($id);
//$modeldetail = new salesdetail();
```

then the error would be "Call to undefined method app\models\salesdetail::findModel()"

can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong ?
and how to get appropriate data from salesdetail based on salesheader and put it on dropdownlist ?

Thank you for ur help

Comment: Please also post ur model class , if it is big , remove the methods added by you. But include namespace , class definition , extended methods. Also ActiveRecord class doesnt have a method called `findModel` which points to the second error

Comment: @ck_arjun, if ActiveRecord dont have `findModel`, then what about this one : `$model = $this->findModel($id);`, i mean how to get appropriate record from salesdetail based on sales header and put it on dropdownlist on my view, since dropdownlist would need model

Comment: if u want to get a model instance using primary key `ModelClass::findOne($id)` would do. But seeing the code snipet you have posted ,  i infer that you should go through the entire documentation. Its pretty neat and easy to understand. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Comment: `$model = $this->findModel($id);` is referring to the controller function `findModel` unless u post that method definition here I cant say whats wrong with it.

Comment: Adding the classes for models will help us alot understand your problem. Please add them :)

Comment: @ck_arjun, i have add my model for salesheader and salesdetail. if i use `$mymodel = ModelClass::findOne($id);` like u suggest, can i use it on my dropdownlist like this : `<?= $form->field($mymodel, 'itemId')->dropDownList($item)->label(false) ?>`  and how i can achieve that ?

Comment: @Ivan ActiveForm Field requires an ActiveRecord Instance as the first parameter. So yes u can use `$mymodel`. Also `$detail` in your current code is Array of `salesdetail` objects which cannot be used.